# xcuitrunner not starting, no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: windows, ios

We're able to start xcuitrunner on most of our machines. On one machine, we still get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it: [_IP ADDRESS]:27015
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapShot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress[] addresses, Int32 port)
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port)
  at Quamotion.Devices.iOS.Managed.MuxerDeviceClient.Connect(Boolean forceTcp, String muxerHost, Int32 muxerPort)
  at Quamotion.Devices.iOS.Managed.MuxerDeviceClient.ListDevices(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<Main>b__2()
  at Microsoft.Extension.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
  at XcuitRunner.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The Apple Mobile Device Service is running, and iTunes and tools like `idevicesyslog` can see the device just fine.

Is there a solution for this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd! Can you share the following information:

1. The full error message. You've excluded the IP address from the error message. Can you please share the exact error message? The IP address should be 127.0.0.1, or the IPv6 equivalent.
2. Can you double check the Apple Mobile Device Service is running?
3. Can you share the output of `netstat -a -p tcp` and `netstat -a -p tcpv6`? Is a service listening on port 27015? On 127.0.0.1 or ::1?
4. Can you run `ping localhost` and `ping -4 localhost`? Does it give different outputs on the machine where it works & doesn’t work?

Comment: Localhost was pointing to a specific IP instead of 127.0.0.1. Fixed that, and it started working. Good catch!